# How to get post from specific category using REST api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am using rest API to get the post from a specific Category.
but from this URL `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/?slug=category_name` I am only getting the category name, not the post.

**and by using this link**

[Check this link](http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=category_name)

I am getting all the post but not getting the featured image in that post.

**note: I am using the better-featured image**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the category ID.
Example: http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=3160